# /etc/shadow file permissions keep resetting on ubuntu server

Tags: security

I want to experiment with pentesting. For that reason I want to have the /etc/shadow file have 777 permissions. But after I set them, randomly it seems to me, they get reset to 660.

I found that apparmor has an 'authentication' abstraction that references the shadow file. Is this maybe it? I am going crazy over this.

BTW, I know it is a bad idea to change the permissions but I really want to do it for my playground server.

Edit: Maybe it is me, using passwd to set some password that resets the permissions. So the question is then if anyone knows if any service interferes with the shadow file permissions. If not, it must be the passwd utility.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu Server 17.10

Answer (score 0):

You could use `auditd` to find the process that is changing the permissions:

1. `sudo apt install auditd`
2. `sudo auditctl -a exit,always -F path=/etc/shadow -k "etcshadow"`
3. [wait until permissions changed]
4. `sudo ausearch -i -k etcshadow`

This will install the auditd package and register an auditing rule for `/etc/shadow` under the name *etcshadow*. The last command is to search the audit event database for entries created by the previously registered rule.